# Does a left Kan lift of a homset functor Hom(*, - ): C -> {Set} through the forgetful functor {M-Set} -> {Set} exist?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $M$ be a monoid and let $\mathsf{U} : M\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ denote the functor which forgets the action on an $M$-set.

Given a category $C$ with a distinguished object $p$ as baspoint, does a left Kan lift of $\mathrm{Hom}_{C}( p , - ) : C \to \mathsf{Set}$ through $\mathsf{U}$ exist?

Comment: what happens if C = Set and p is a singleton. does a lift exist there? if so, what is it? (I'm just trying to understand your question in more concrete terms)

Comment: In your example, the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{C}(p, - )$ will be the identity functor on $\mathsf{Set}$. In that case, the question is just asking whether the forgetful functor $\mathsf{U}$ has a left adjoint.

Comment: Indeed, the functor from $\mathsf{Set}$ to $M\mathsf{Set}$ which sends a set $X$ to the $M$-set $X$ with the trivial action is left adjoint to $\mathsf{U}$.

Comment: Thanks, pro, you suggestion has basically answered my question in the affirmative. Since $\mathsf{U}$ has a left adjoint, the required left Kan lift exists.

Comment: hah. I was actually thinking it couldn't work. I had in mind the functor sending a set to the free M-module generated from it. Composing with forgetting the M-structure would certainly not give the identity on Set. But I hadn't thought about the trivial action. Anyway, I'm not sure if having an adjoint answers your question, but I'm happy if you're happy.